# image not showing in pdf from jupyter with nbconvert

Tags: pdf, jupyter

I'm trying to create a pdf from a notebook file, but when I export as pdf, either by choosing download from the menu or with

```
jupyter nbconvert Week\ 1\ -\ Welcome\ to\ Python.ipynb --to pdf
```

any images included (with html) are not showing up.

if I export as html like

```
jupyter nbconvert Week\ 1\ -\ Welcome\ to\ Python.ipynb --to html
```

It works fine, but if I choose download as html, the images don't embed.

Converting to slides is also working fine.

I'm using jupyter 4.1.0 on linux mint 17.3